# how to wrap elements in each divs

Tags: jquery, html

I have two block with the same classes in which the content - is the title and description. How to collect all the titles into one div and placed above description.

What I have now

```
<div class="div">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <p>some text</p>
    <div class="title"></div>
    <p>some text</p>
    <div class="title"></div>
    <p>some text</p>
    <div class="title"></div>
</div>

<div class="div">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <p>some text</p>
    <div class="title"></div>
    <p>some text</p>
    <div class="title"></div>
    <p>some text</p>
    <div class="title"></div>
</div>
```

want this result -----------------------------------------------

```
<div class="div">
    <div class="container-for-title">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="title"></div>
    </div>

    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>

<div class="div">
    <div class="container-for-title">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div class="title"></div>
    </div>

    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/),

```
$(".div").each(function() {
  $(".title", this).wrapAll($("<div>", {
    class: "container-for-title"
  }));
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ym0nLv6k/)

Comment: @AndreyShandrov Glad to help! :)